# Windows 8 on a newly bought laptop

Tags: windows-8, license

I just bought a new ASUS laptop with Windows 8 installed on it in a well-known store. I didn't get and CD of Windows 8, nor any written license attesting that I am the legal owner of that Windows 8 installation. My questions:

1. Should I go back to the store and demand that they give me a written license? Or maybe it's not required because the license is somehow "built in" the computer? (sorry for the newbie question... I am new to Windows. In the Linux world there is no such thing).
2. Should I go back to the store and demand that they give me a Windows 8 CD, so that I can reinstall Windows if I erase it by accident? Or maybe nowadays it is possible to reinstall Windows 8 without a CD? (how?)

Comment: Most laptops that come with Windows 8 installed nowadays usually have a recovery partition containing the Windows installer. If I remember correctly, keys are also stored in the BIOS/UEFI firmware, in the ACPI (SLIC) table. The Windows installer detects it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No you do not need the disc or written license.

Long answer:
I don't think the disc will be needed. And the store won't GIVE you a disc, because the manufacturer of your laptop most likely charges around 30 US Dollars for them. Depending on your manufacturer you should have a hidden system partition with the contents of the said disc plus the drivers, and this is accessed by pressing a certain button upon boot (the button is usually F10 or something and it will come up on the screen).

One of the improvements Microsoft is making to Activation 3.0 for newly built machines that come preloaded with Windows 8, you won’t have a COA (Certificate of Authenticity) sticker attached to the machine anymore. Instead, this will be embedded in the BIOS. This will avoid product keys from being compromised and OEMs will buy what they need.

Comment: I click F10 after power-up and nothing happens... How can I see the Windows 8 that is installed on the partition?

Comment: I looked it up, and for your manufacturer (ASUS) you actually need to press F9, this needs to be done when the laptop is starting up from the very beginning where is says ASUS on the screen, I usually tap the button repeatedly until the menu comes up, or the machine beeps at me. Good Luck!

Comment: If my answer helped you, please select my answer.